# How to draw a circle in OpenGL 1.0 in Android Studio that moves from the center to right and then to left

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

This is my code, before some changes it was drawing a blue circle on green background. I don't have any idea how to fix that problem. I was trying many things. The first problem is that it looks distorted, it it more oval that circle, first idea was to create seperate function which was called out in onSurfaceChanged
`DrawCircle(gl,  width,  height)`  it helped me to get correct shape of circle, but I was not able to move it like in the pattern shown below.

```
package pl.varkame;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.os.SystemClock;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;


public class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private float kat=0;
    public FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private DrawCircle Circlek;
    private int n_seg=720; // number of segments
    float[] vertices = new float[n_seg*2+2];
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        Circlek = new DrawCircle();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        float ratio = (float) width/(float) height;
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl,45.0f,(float)width/(float)height,-1.0f, -10.0f);
        gl.glOrthof(-ratio, ratio, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glColor4f(0.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f , 1.0f);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        Circlek.draw();
    }
}

class DrawCircle{
    public FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    public int c=0;
    private int n_seg=720; // number of segments
    float[] vertices = new float[n_seg*2+2];
    public float width = 100;
    public float height= 50;
    float ratio = width/height;

    public void Circle(GL10 gl) {
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer(); 
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);     
        vertexBuffer.position(0);        
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(2 , GL10.GL_FLOAT , 0 , vertexBuffer);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN , 0 , vertices.length / 2);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    }

    public void draw(){
        for (int i=0; i<n_seg;i++){
            float radius=0.1f ;
            double rad=(Math.PI*2*i/n_seg);
            vertices[c]=(float)Math.cos(rad)*radius;
            vertices[c+1]=(float) Math.sin(rad)*(radius/ratio);
            c+=2;
        }
    }

}
```

I was trying to animate this movement with any success

[image: movement]

This was last working code, circle was distorted in it

```
package pl.varkame;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLU;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private float kat=0;
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl,45.0f,(float)width/(float)height,-1.0f, -10.0f);
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
        int c=0;
        int n_seg=720; // number of segments
        float[] vertices = new float[n_seg*2+2];
        for (int i=0; i<n_seg;i++){
            float radius=0.1f ; // 10% z szerokości ekranu
            double rad=(Math.PI*2*i/n_seg);
            vertices[c]=(float)Math.cos(rad)*radius;
            vertices[c+1]=(float) Math.sin(rad)*radius;
            c+=2;
        }
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer(); 
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);    
        vertexBuffer.position(0);  

        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN,0,vertices.length/2);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);` before `gl.glLoadIdentity()`.

Comment: Its probably a side-effect of you hardcoding 45 in the line:  GLU.gluPerspective(gl,45.0f,(float)width/(float)height,-1.0f, -10.0f);
How do you know its even 45 for your device?